# remove string between parentheses [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

i have a NSString with parentheses in it.
I would like to remove the Text inside of the parentheses.
How to do that? ( In Objective-C )

Example String:

> Tach auch. (lockeres Ruhrdeutsch) Und Hallo!

I would like to Remove "(lockeres Ruhrdeutsch)" from the String,
but the Strings i have to edit are always different.
How can i remove the String betweeen "(" and ")"?

Best Regards

Answer (score 5):

Use regular expression:

```
NSString *string = @"Tach auch. (lockeres Ruhrdeutsch) Und Hallo!";
NSString *filteredString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\(.*\\)" 
                                                             withString:@"" 
                                                                options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
NSLog(@"%@", filteredString);
```

If you want to consider also a whitespace character after the closing parenthesis, add `\\s?` to the end of the regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function you can call to get your required string:

```
-(NSString*)getStringWithBlankParaFrom:(NSString*)oldStr{

    NSArray*strArray1=[oldStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
    NSString*str2=[strArray1 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSArray*strArray2 =[str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
    NSString*strToReplace=[strArray2 objectAtIndex:0];

    return [oldStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:strToReplace withString:@""];
}
```

This function is valid for the string which contains one pair of parentheses**()**

You can change it as per your requirement.
Hope this helps!